# How to get videos link from a given URL in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, url, video

I want to make a C/C++ program which will be able to fetch all video link available on a particular site(www.youtube.com) and that links will be saved in a file. I have search much for this but could not get any efficient information.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank in advance

Comment: C++ isn't best language for this. You should consider using javascript. Your web browser creates some links dynamically, so if you write something like simple web browser, it won't be able to work 100% correctly.

Comment: You're asking about the whole application? Or fetching the data? I'd use CURL ( http://curl.haxx.se/ ), parse the content of fetched HTML with a regex to find all linked video resources.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz The task can be easily done by any language.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Thanks for Reply... Can you please give any link which will helpful to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

First download the html page by opening socket or using [libcurl](/questions/tagged/libcurl). Then Look for html anchors in the source that has patterns like `watch?v=ASs8odtJjLI`. Theses are the video links.

You can get the sample curl code by invoking `curl` in the command line directly.

```
curl --libcurl sample_curl.c 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASs8odtJjLI'
```

Now change the `sample_curl.c` according to your need. For parsing use a HTML parser.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I think this may help me. So, I have to go through this and i'll be back to you soon...